# How to reset user's password in Google Apps Script using admin SDK?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I have a list newly creates users in my domain. I want to reset all of their password. But I don't want to do it using admin console. How can I do this using admin SDK and Google App script?

My idea is get a list of user whose password I need to reset, and then assign some random strings to those email id's and update it as their password.

I this possible? If not, is there any better idea? (I have tried using GAM, But I don't want to do it through CSV files each time.)

Answer (score 1):

Resetting a password is possible via the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_user) within the Admin SDK; therefore, you would be able to do this via Apps Script.

Depending how comfortable you are with coding, you might want to use [Google Apps Manager](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) to complete this and other tasks. The command to change a password can be found [here](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GAM3DirectoryCommands#update-and-rename-a-user). These types of commands can be run in [bulk](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/BulkOperations) by either reading a CSV of all users (can also be created with GAM) or writing a small script to go through a group, OU, etc. and reset only those users.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample function, using the [Directory API (Admin-SDK-service)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) in Apps Script that you could use to update a users password.

```
function updatePassword(userId,newPassword){
  try {
    // Define the user's new password
    var newPasswordObject = {
      password: newPassword
    };
    
    // Update the user's password
    AdminDirectory.Users
    .update(newPasswordObject, userId);
    
    console.log("Password updated successfully for user: " + userId);
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error updating password: " + e.toString());
  }
}
```

If you want to loop over a spreadsheet containing useraccounts and passwords,  a possible solution could look like this.

Add this function to an Apps Script Project within a Spreadsheet with data.

```
function loopOverSheetWithUsersAndPasswords(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  // Assuming you have a sheet with the name 'LIST OF USERS AND PASSWORDS'
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('LIST OF USERS AND PASSWORDS')

  // We wont be using the headers, we only need the actual data.
  var [headers, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  /* Assuming that the sheet looks like this:   
    |  Usernames      |  Password       |
    --------------------------------------
    |  john@m.tk      |  p@$$w0rd123    |
    |  anny@m.tk      |  p@$$w0rd456    |
        ...                  ...
  */
  
  data.forEach((row)=>{
    var username = row[0]
    var newPassword = row[1]
    // if both username and newpassword are provided, change the password.
    if (username && newPassword) {
        updatePassword(username,newPassword)
    }
  })
}
```